# pdo_firebird extension in WAMP

Tags: php, apache, wamp, firebird, wamp64

I currently have WAMP with PHP 7.3.21 and Apache 2.4.46. I'm trying connect to a Firebird database. I have already done the following steps to load Firebird extension.

1. Remove the semi colon for extension=pdo_firebird;
2. Place fbclient.dll file in apache/bin folder.

However when I run my phpinfo, I can't see the Firebird driver. Anything else that I need to do to be able to run the Firebird extension?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I did the following things:

- Installed wamp64 3.2.6 (with PHP 7.3.33 enabled)
- Changed wamp config to use PHP 7.3.33
- Enabled pdo_firebird:

  - Click on the wamp tray icon
  - Choose PHP > PHP extensions
  - Choose pdo_firebird

With this done, pdo_firebird does not show up in phpinfo(), unless the 64-bit fbclient.dll is already installed.

I dropped a 64-bit fbclient.dll into `D:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.51\bin`, and restarted all services (via the wamp tray icon), and the PDO_Firebird entry showed up in the phpinfo() report, and "firebird" is listed for "PDO drivers" under "PDO support".

If I had to guess, you tried to use a **32-bit** fbclient.dll instead of a **64-bit** fbclient.dll.

Alternative methods to install a 64-bit fbclient.dll:

1. Use the 64-bit installer from https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-4-0/#Win64 and select "Minimum client install - no server, no tools."
2. Download the 64-bit "zip kit" from https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-4-0/#Win64, unzip it, and - from a command prompt run as administrator - execute `instclient i f`
3. Download the 64-bit "zip kit" from https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-4-0/#Win64, unzip it, and copy/paste fbclient.dll to `%WINDIR%\system32`